# Как открыть программу с БД созданный на MS SQL Server на компьютере, где нет MS SQL?

Tags: c#

Создал программу на C# с DataGrid и на MS SQL SERVER. Но он не отображается на другом компьютере при запуске. Там не установлена MS SQL. Как решить данную проблему и чтобы она корректно отобразилась? Кто поможет?

Comment: Установить ms sql server express

Comment: а без него никак нельзя? @Flash

Comment: Если вы хотите работать с MS SQL, то без него никак. 
Можно еще работать с SQLite или XML, но, думаю, в вашем случае проще будет установить MS SQL Express.

Answer (score 1):

1) Установите MS SQL Express. 
2) Установить .NET Framework

Других вариантов нет.